# Error when configuring ECR authorization token with docker login

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

I am running into this error when trying to setup ECR authorization token  with docker login.
Can you please advice

echo $(aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 --profile test)|docker login --password-stdin --username AWS 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `not implemented`

Comment: There were an answer from the OP, but now deleted: It worked after resetting docker.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using works with AWS CLI v2. The `not implemented` message may mean you don't have the latest version OR you are using AWS CLI v1? For AWS CLI v1 there is another (similar) command which calls `get-login`. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html).